# Ambiguous grammar to equivalent unambiguous grammar

Tags: automata, formal-grammars

I stumbled on this ambiguous grammar and I've been trying to make it unambiguous but it's still ambiguous.

Given the ambiguous CFG :
$S \to A\mid B$
$A \to aAb\mid ab$
$B \to abB\mid \epsilon$

My closet try was:

Given the ambiguous CFG :
$S \to A$
$A \to aAb\mid C$
$B \to b$
$C \to abC\mid\epsilon$

But the string "$ab$" is ambiguous

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Here is a good series of questions to get you started: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-grammars%2bambiguity

Comment: In fact, the original CFG does not generate generate $aababb$, which is generated by your CFG as follows, $S\Rightarrow A\Rightarrow aAb\Rightarrow aCb\Rightarrow aabCb\Rightarrow aababCb\Rightarrow aababb$.

Comment: Oh true, those that mean there isn't a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have observed, the only problem in the original CFG is that the string $ab$ can be generated by both $A$ and $B$.

Here is a hint. Instead of generating $ab, a^2b^2, a^3b^3,\cdots$, can you let $A$ generate $a^2b^2, a^3b^3,\cdots$ without generating $ab$?

Comment: Any idea on how to implement that?

Comment: How did you avoid an ambiguous parse of the empty string?

Comment: @OwonubiJobSunday Instead of $A\to aAb\mid ab$, how about $A\to aAb\mid a^2b^2$?

Comment: @rici can the empty string be parsed in two ways in the original CFG?

Comment: @apass.jack. no, it can't. Why not? Because the base productions differ.

Comment: @rici, agreed. So what do you mean by "How did you avoid an ambiguous parse of the empty string?" since there is no ambiguous parse of the empty string in the first place? Were you talking to OP instead of me?

Comment: @apass: yes, sorry.

Comment: @Apass, I don't understand what you mean.. I've given my all to solve it and that was my closest try. Making me to think if we could really convert it to unambiguous

Comment: Just replace the single rule $A\to ab$ in the original CFG to $A\to a^2b^2$.

Comment: Then we won't be able to get "ab"

Comment: $ab$ is generated by $B$, $S\Rightarrow B\Rightarrow abB\Rightarrow ab$. It looks like you did not realize the ambiguity of the original CFG comes from $ab$ can be generated by $A$ and $B$. Is it clear now?

Comment: It's very clear. I'm glad and grateful